# Change camera aperture for PhotoCaptureDevice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

## Context

I was looking at the PhotoCaptureDevice class in the Windows Phone 8 API docs and noticed that there's no property for setting the camera aperture on the device. I can specify a lot of other properties, such as EV compensation and white balance, but not the aperture.

## Question

Is it correct to assume that the cameras in Windows Phone 8 devices can't have their aperture changed? And more importantly, does this mean it's controlled automatically or do all pictures have the same aperture setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the current Windows Phone cameras have a fixed camera aperture as far as I know, so this isn't possible.